# Meteor NPM - can’t import owl.Carousel

Tags: meteor, npm, owl-carousel

Following meteor docs I've installed [Owl.Carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/owl.carousel) with this command:

```
meteor npm install --save owl.carousel
```

Now I have it in `node_modules/owl.carousel`

I am trying to `Import` it exactly like stated here - [Using NPM packages](http://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#using-npm) :

```
import owl.Carousel from 'owl.carousel';
```

but at the build time I get this error:

```
While building for web.browser: imports/startup/client/index.js:5:10: Unexpected token (5:10).
```

5:10 is the point in import statement: `import owl` **this point->**`.Carousel from 'owl.carousel';`

***Where is my mistake? How should I import Owl.Carousel?***

Comment: ever find a solution?

Comment: Yes. `import owlCarousel from 'owl.carousel';` - works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import owlCarousel from 'owl.carousel';` - works.

Comment: How you're supposed to figure these things out is still a mystery to me.

Comment: It's ES6 import syntax. This could help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import Back in those days it was hard for me to grasp that too.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't talking about ES6 syntax. I'm talking about how you're supposed to know to use `owlCarousel` with no period when the entire NPM page says to import `owl.carousel`. I'm learning that if it's a JQuery function you want to import, you import the function like this.  Yet on other packages, you import them like `owl.carousel/dist/js/owl.carousel.js`.  It always seems to be a mystery for each package. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `import owl.Carousel from 'owl.carousel'` because `owl.Carousel` is invalid syntax. Try one of the following:

```
import owl from 'owl.carousel';
// or
import { Carousel } from 'owl.carousel';
```